# Room/sqlite database locks & isolation levels

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

(the question is in context of kotlin android app with mvvm pattern and room/sqlite database)

Lets say i have an android app with a screen with a form to create sole entity.

For example, i create an object/entity like this (pseudo code):

```
class Trip {
  string id;
  string name;
  datetime date;
  string countryId;
}
```

now, `countryId` references country table and it stores countries info like:

```
class Country {
  string id;
  string name;
  string countryCode;
  boolean allowedForTravel;
}
```

now, when i get to `Trip` creation screen i have input fields for `name, date` and there is a dropdown to choose a country. that dropdown gets filled with `SELECT * FROM Countries WHERE allowedForTravel = true`.

so, imagine scenario:

1. user comes to trip creation screen
2. countries dropdown gets filled
3. user chooses country X from dropdown
4. countryX gets updated in database by some other process (push notifications or whatever) to now have `allowedForTravel= false`
5. used fills `name,date` for trip
6. user hits `save` button

i would like to save this in a transaction in order to be able to check at write time if chosen country is allowed for trips.

how to accomplish this using Room & SQLlite?

i believe some transaction and isolation levels should be used but dont know which and how?

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't it be better to wrap the country list in some observable like `LiveData` so that if `allowedForTravel` changes on the currently selected country, you can notify the user directly on the form and disable the save button?

Comment: @glucaio thanks for your comment! its probably possible and sounds like a good additional thing that helps good ux but i would also like to have it atomic in database transaction.

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html

Comment: @Diego Torres Milano thanks for the link! that is the first article i’ve read but i must say i dont get it completely. So, if i understand correctly, 1. transactions are SERIALIZABLE by default. That should mean that no 2 transactions can run concurrently. Does that mean that if my transaction from question starts with SELECT *  that the result of that SELECT is guaranteed to stay the same until the end of that transaction? 2. Does concurrency between different/same connection plays any role in that? 3. could you please share some high-overview example of Room code how to implement it?